# Efficient computation of "higher order" Jacobi symbols

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, algorithms

Let $N> 1$, and suppose $a \in (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. There are efficient algorithms to compute the Jacobi symbol $\left(\frac{a}{N}\right)$ using quadratic reciprocity. Fix $k \geq 1$. I would like an efficient algorithm to compute the "higher-order" Jacobi symbol, which measures whether $a$ is $2^k$-power mod $N$. When $N$ is prime, the algorithm should output 1 if there exists an integer $x$ such that $x^{2^k} \equiv a \pmod{N}$ and should output $-1$ otherwise; when $N$ is composite, this symbol should be extended in the same way the Legendre symbol is extended to the Jacobi symbol.

I think the following algorithm works in the special case when $N$ is prime: we first check if $a$ is a quadratic residue mod $N$ by computing the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{a}{N}\right)$. If not, we know it cannot be a $2^k$ power. If so, we recursively check whether $\pm a^{1/2}$ is a $2^{k-1}$ power. Note that since there are two square roots, this algorithm may involve exponentially many recursive calls; I suspect there is a way to make this algorithm run in polynomial time. I'm not sure how to approach this problem when $N$ is a composite integer with unknown factorization - I'm hoping someone here will know!

Comment: Note that the problem of efficiently computing (for $N$ an integer of unknown factorization, and $e$ some fixed constant) $x\mapsto x^{1/e}\bmod N$ is thought to be hard --- being able to compute this immediately breaks the RSA cryptosystem. This is slightly different than what you want (you only use $e = 2^k$, RSA typically uses $e = 2^k+1$, and you only care about the "decision" problem), but what you want is at least adjacent to a plausibly hard problem.

Comment: I think worth noting explicitly that this "higher order" symbol is not multiplicative  even for N prime - the product of two non 2^k powers is not necessarily a 2^k power, because the 2^k powers are not index 2 in the multiplicative group for k>1.